# analytics - google tutorial for measuring referrals - is this tutorial ok?

Tags: android, google-analytics

According to Google Analytics Campaign Measuring (**version 3**) I followed by theirs tutorial, but in `onStart` we only create calls `MapBuilder.createAppView()` without sending this data, should I change it to

```
EasyTracker.getInstance(this).send(MapBuilder.createAppView().setAll(getReferrerMapFromUri(uri)).build());
```

? I think there is an error because I don't see any refferals on my Google Analytics Panel.

Here is the [Google Analytics Campaing Measuring](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/campaigns?hl=pl#general-campaigns) code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private static final String GA_PROPERTY_ID = "UA-XXXX-Y";
  private static final String SCREEN_LABEL = "Home Screen";

  private static final String CAMPAIGN_SOURCE_PARAM = "utm_source";
  Tracker mTracker;
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mTracker = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).getTracker(GA_PROPERTY_ID);
  }
  @Override
  public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mTracker.set(Fields.SCREEN_NAME, SCREEN_LABEL);

    Intent intent = this.getIntent();
    Uri uri = intent.getData();

    MapBuilder.createAppView().setAll(getReferrerMapFromUri(uri));
  }

  Map<String,String> getReferrerMapFromUri(Uri uri) {
    MapBuilder paramMap = new MapBuilder();

    if (uri == null) { return paramMap.build(); }
    if (uri.getQueryParameter(CAMPAIGN_SOURCE_PARAM) != null) {
      paramMap.setCampaignParamsFromUrl(uri.toString());
     } else if (uri.getAuthority() != null) {
       paramMap.set(Fields.CAMPAIGN_MEDIUM, "referral");
       paramMap.set(Fields.CAMPAIGN_SOURCE, uri.getAuthority());
     }
     return paramMap.build();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, how did you solved this ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem.
To retrieve the "general campaign and traffic source attribution", I tried the sample code of https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/campaigns

And my Uri is generated by "Google Play URL Builder"
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flipr.ga3&referrer=utm_source%3Dsource3%26utm_medium%3Dmedium3%26utm_term%3Dterm3%26utm_content%3Dcontent3%26utm_campaign%3Dcampaign3"

When click the app and it did launch my app. But the "`getQueryParameter(CAMPAIGN_SOURCE_PARAM)`" returned `null`.

I found the exact parameter name in Uri is "`referrer`", instead of "`utm_source`".
I think that's why the `getQueryParameter(CAMPAIGN_SOURCE_PARAM)` returned `null`.

I think the sample is wrong and we should:
1. `String str1 = getQueryParameter("referrer")`
2. Then, retrieve all the key-vaue pairs into map
3. `createAppView().setAll(map)`

Comment: BTW, there is no more "General campaign & traffic source measurement" in v4 document...  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. On some level. 
Documentation editor have done too much operation.
Instead:

`MapBuilder.createAppView().setAll(getReferrerMapFromUri(uri));`

Should be:

```
mTracker.send(getReferrerMapFromUri(uri));
```

Because .send() needs Map and the getReferrerMapFromUri(uri) return this.